# Changing a readonly input text in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an association where a code has an influencer. 
I want to show the influencer username as readonly in the code form.

Right now I'm doing:

```
form do |f|
f.inputs 'Code' do
  f.input :influencer, input_html: { readonly: true, disabled: true  }, as: :string if !f.object.new_record?
```

But I get this and I want the influencer name or username.

[image: I need a field displayed. Not the object.]

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up adding this line in the code model

```
delegate :username, to: :influencer, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

and then this in the form:

```
f.input :influencer_username,
          label: 'Influencer',
          input_html: { readonly: true, disabled: true },
          as: :string unless f.object.new_record?
```